# docker-compose ADD a tarball outside (or inside) of build context always fails no matter what

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-engine

I've got the following dir tree:

```
project_root
|- build_script.sh
|- dir_1/Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml
|- tarball_dir/
```

I've got the `build_script.sh` which calls `docker-compose` like so:

`docker-compose -f ./dir_1/docker-compose.yml build --build-arg BUILD_ID=$BUILD_ID dev`

This is the `Dockerfile`:

```
 FROM elixir:1.5.2

  ARG BUILD_ID
  ENV APP_HOME /app
  RUN mkdir $APP_HOME

  # Copy release tarball and unpack
~ ADD ../dir_1/${BUILD_ID}.tar.gz $APP_HOME/

  CMD $APP_HOME/bin/my_app foreground
```

And this is the `docker-compose-yml`:

```
version: '2'

  services:
    common:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
      networks:
        - default

    dev:
      extends:
        service: common
      env_file:
        - ./dev.env
      environment:
        POSTGRES_HOST: "postgres.dev"
        MIX_ENV: dev
      ports:
        - "4000:4000"
      depends_on:
        - postgres
```

I want to be able to `ADD` (so that it copies and unpacks the tarball) into the image. However, after trying endless combinations of Docker context directories and trying to include the tarball into the image, I always get one of two errors:

```
ERROR: Service 'dev' failed to build: ADD failed: Forbidden path outside the build context: ../tarball_dir/tarball.tar.gz ()
```

or

```
ERROR: Service 'dev' failed to build: ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder887135091/tarball_dir/tarball.tar.gz: no such file or directory
```

I would like to keep this directory structure, if possible. I've managed to build and run the container with the following command:

```
docker build \
--build-arg BUILD_ID=$BUILD_ID \
-t my_app:$BUILD_ID \
-f dir_1/Dockerfile .

docker run \
--network my_app_network \
--env-file ./dir_1/$ENV.env \
 my_app:$BUILD_ID
```

But I can't reproduce this same behaviour using `docker-compose` no matter what.

I'm on Mac OS Sierra and I'm using Docker Edge Version 17.10.0-ce-mac36 (19824) Channel: edge a7c7e01149

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible, maybe it's worth consider a multi stage build: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/multistage-build/

Comment: Is your tar file in dir_1 or tarball_dir? An MCVE may be better than the partial example here.

Comment: @BMitch tarball_dir. What's an MCVE?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve